Umbilical points under isometries
In a certain question I have been asked to say if it is true that given a surface $S$, if a point $p$ is umbilical then under an isometry $f$ with another surface $S'$ the transformed point $f(p) \in S'$ is also umbilical.

I have the feeling that it is true. What I tried is the following: given that $p$ is umbilical, Gaussian curvature shows that for any direction $w$, $I = \lambda II$, where $II, I$ are the second and first fundamental forms, respectively, which means that for each direction both fundamental forms remain proportional with constant $\lambda$. An isometry conserved Gaussian curvature and first fundamental form, so the determinant of $II$ is conserved, not $II$ itself. I would need to show that the eigenvalues of the shape operator $-I^{-1} \cdot f(II)$ (abuse of notation, I meant the second fundamental form under the isometry) are the same as the original one (there is only one because it is umbilic point). I don't know how to continue. I would be grateful if somebdoy could give me a hint or tell me that it is false.

Besides, as an offtopic related to other question (I promise this is simpler), does second fundamental form equal zero for a curve (which means it is an asymptotic curve) in a surface imply that the curve is planar? I guess it is true since it means that the shape operator is zero which implies that the normal vector to the surface is constant for that curve.

This would mean that a point being umbilic is an intrinsic property and this is not true. Indeed, the standard example of isometric surfaces and open part of a cylinder and an open part of a plane provides a counter example since in the plane all points are umbilic while the cylinder does not have umbilic points.
